# sql query not pulling records the same

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT Book.title, Book.copyright, Book.publisher, Book.id,
    MaterialType.type, Item.id as item_id, 100 as relevance FROM `books` AS `Book`
inner JOIN `material_types` AS `MaterialType` ON (`MaterialType`.`id` = `Book`.`material_type_id`)
inner JOIN `items` AS `Item` ON (`Item`.`book_id` = `Book`.`id` AND `Item`.`accession_number` = '0936')
WHERE 1 = 1  GROUP BY `Book`.`id`
```

which pulls up nothing. HOWEVER, if i do this query it finds the right record:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` AS `Item` WHERE `Item`.`accession_number` = '0936'
```

The strangest part though, other records it will work for. if I use the accession_number 0396, if finds the right record in both queries. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the purpose of the where and group by clauses? Without aggregate functions grouping is pointless, and a where clause that always evaluates to true is equality pointless. However, since the simplified select does find something, make sure that the retrieved item records have a matching book.id. Without that, your innerjoin will prevent anything from showing up.

Comment: auto-generated by the program as a default value if there isn't a where condition specified. plus, that actually is an extraction out of a query, but that is the part that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use LEFT JOIN with matierial_types because it is possible that this table doesn't have the same materialType id of books
try this

```
SELECT Book.title, Book.copyright, Book.publisher, Book.id,
    MaterialType.type, Item.id as item_id, 100 as relevance FROM `books` AS `Book`
LEFT JOIN `material_types` AS `MaterialType` ON (`MaterialType`.`id` = `Book`.`material_type_id`)
LEFT JOIN `items` AS `Item` ON (`Item`.`book_id` = `Book`.`id`) 
WHERE `Item`.`accession_number` = '0936'
GROUP BY `Book`.`id`
```

Comment: try it again with LEFT JOIN, are you sure accession_number a string ?

Comment: this is due to missing records. inner join works only if both table contains the exact id, however left join also include the null entries. Actually in your case material_type or items has not records according to condition in join statement

Comment: add that explanation to your main answer. and to be exact, it was the material types that doesn't exist. so the correct way, since I require the items, is left join for types and inner join for items.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have no entry in 'Book' that corresponds to an item with an 'accession_number' of 0936. A Right Join to Items should reveal this:

```
SELECT Book.title, Book.copyright, Book.publisher, Book.id,
    MaterialType.type, Item.id as item_id, 100 as relevance FROM `books` AS `Book`
left JOIN `material_types` AS `MaterialType` ON (`MaterialType`.`id` = `Book`.`material_type_id`)
right JOIN `items` AS `Item` ON (`Item`.`book_id` = `Book`.`id` AND `Item`.`accession_number` = '0936')
WHERE 1 = 1  GROUP BY `Book`.`id`
```

Comment: actually there is. that was the first thing i checked